# Integration tests do not run under profile

Tags: maven

I have the following directory structure for my maven project:

```
   |-src
   |---itest
   |-----java
   |-------com
   |---------corp
   |-----------div
   |-------------dept
   |---------------prod
   |-----------------config
   |-------------------integration
   |---------------------PersistenceConfig.java
   |-----------------test
   |-------------------LandingPageInfoTest.java
   |-----resources
   |-------db
   |---------migration
   |-----------V1__SeedLandingPageInfo.sql
   |-------log4j.properties
   |-------persistence.properties
```

(note: src/**i** test, not src/test)

I have an appropriate set of `build-helper-maven-plugin` plugin declarations that tell maven to add `src/itest/java` and `src/itest/resources` via the `add-test-source` and `add-test-resource` goals.

Everything works great when I run `mvn test` from the command line.

**The problem:** when I move my plugin declarations into a separate `<profile>` named `integration` my tests refuse to run when I execute `mvn test -Pintegration` and I'm not sure why...

Comment: Can you share your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: @Mureinik Here you are: https://gist.github.com/ctataryn/8b53857c4fd286ccadc1

Comment: I don't know the cause of your immediate problem, but there is a Maven convention for running integration tests. Running `mvn test` should compile and run unit tests. This should be fast for developers. Running `mvn verify` (which also occurs during `install` or `deploy`) is the correct way to run integration tests. Unit test class names end in `Test` and integration tests have a different ending - often `IT`.

Comment: @DavidV Thanks, I'll look into that. I typically have, in the past, lump all Integration tests into one separate module that I'd only run when I want to do a smoke test.  However for my new project I'd like to keep integration tests right in the module they apply to, therefore my want of keeping them in a separate folder within the module.

Comment: I imagine that there is a way to separate the integration test directory out of the test directory, but I've never tried. I normally just use a different package for my integration tests (e.g. `integration`) combined with the `IT` suffix.

Comment: After reading this: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/maven/integration-testing-with-maven/ I get it now. Integration tests should run with the verify goal. So after I set it up to more closely align with his pom.xml and renaming my LandingPageTest.java to ITLandingPageTest.java I can now run `mvn verfiy -Pintegration` and my integration test runs.

Comment: @ThaDon, you should no longer need the integration profile. (Unless you wish to distinguish among different environments such as development vs. integration, but this is a very different concept).

Answer (score 0):

The convention tends to be use the maven-failsafe-plugin (http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/) with configuration to include your integration tests whereever they are, even alongside your unit tests, and they should then be excluded from the unit test phase surefire plugin. As a simple example:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <!-- Include your integration test files/directories/suites here -->
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And then you can remove the profile you've specified and as mentioned, only unit tests will be executed in the `test` phase and your integration tests will be executed in the `verify` phase (included before install/deploy).

Following this convention will let you get rid of all the extra plugin configuration to move files around and point at your itest directory.